# moving from another server site broken

Tags: magento2, migration, js-css

I am moving from one server to another server site is broken. Database works fine but issue is css and js not generating. The server is shared hosting. How can I fix the issue??

Comment: Did you run static deploy command?

Comment: yes... but not working... :(

Comment: Is there any Browser error? Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: Do you get an error when running the static deploy command?

Comment: Check pub folder permissions.

Comment: Yes, its solved... permission and deployment problem. Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written an excellent article on solving broken Magento 2 frontend. You can check and see if any one of the below method works for you or not:

- Enable Apache Rewrite
- Fix Files & Folders Permissions
- Delete Generated Files, Sessions & Caches
- Deploy Static View Files

For further reference, please have a look at this blog post.

https://magenticians.com/fix-broken-magento-2-installation/

Comment: yes this is really useful. Though i have fixed my problem, i have a question.
In shared hosting we can not run console, in that case how can we fix the issue.

Comment: @FaysalMahamud Each and every web hosting offers SSH access. You will need to contact your hosting provider administrator to give you SSH credentials so that you can use CLI. I'm not sure about it, but I think they will going to charge you extra for it since by default, shared hosting providers do not offer SSH access.